# How do I send "@here" with the Slack API?

Tags: api, tags, slack-api, slack

I know I can tag a user with `<@U423DFDE|username>` but I can't figure out how to tag `@here`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`<!here>` is the solution. There are other commands that work with the `<!___>` format.

Check out [this part](https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/formatting#special-mentions) of the official Slack documentation for an overview about all such variables.

Comment: Up-to-date link: https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#special-mentions

Answer (score 14):

I use this:

```
var message= {
    "text": "<!here> test text"
} ;
```

Answer (score 1):

For channel use  `<#idchannel>`, for username use `<@memberIdName>`

You can find it here:

[image: where to find member or channel id]