# Slack @here mention in channel via Incoming webhook

Tags: webhooks, slack

So I have an alert channel that collects messages from slack via incoming webhook. It's one of many tools we use to monitor these couple of apps that normally run without issue, but if there is a problem we want to know right away so we can do something about it. I'm getting emails, etc. but I also want the channel wide slack messages.

What I'm trying to do seems simple enough, but it's not working. I want to trigger an @channel or @here message to alert all the users in the channel at the time, so if the error happens in an environment that matters everyone gets a notification. I'm following examples in the documentation using the <@ABC123> channel id but it's not translating into an @here directive, it's just plain text.

Either what I'm doing can't be done, or more likely I'm missing something somewhere or approaching this incorrectly. I'm guessing it's the latter, but at this point confirmation that I can't do what I'm trying to do is fine, I'll come up with something else.

Comment: OK, so username mentions are working just fine, but I don't need to mention a specific user, I want to mention the whole channel (like @channel or @here). I can't find any doc on what to use, other than the Id of the channel, and that isn't working...

Comment: Here is another good answer, which also links to the official docs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120115/how-do-i-send-here-with-the-slack-api/42121313#42121313

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found it
[image]

Apparently the convention for the channel alerts are <!channel>, not <@C123> as is with users or channel ids, or <#channel> with channel mentions (though that does work, just not as a channel wide alert). Hope this helps someone eventually.

Comment: Hunted everywhere for this. Thanks.

Comment: Took me all day to find this. Thank you!